# JSON data to KENDO UI Grid ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json

I have bit trouble getting data to show on my Kendo.Grid.

JSON is valid and it shows when clicking the link as text, but loading the data n the Grid.

Here is the source, any help would be appreciated!

br. Eero

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest  request)
    {
        using (var db = new CimDataContext())
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> customers = db.Customers;
            DataSourceResult result = customers.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(result, "text/x-json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMvcCim.Models.Customer>()
  .Name("grid")
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
      .Ajax() 
      .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Customer")) 
   )
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Id);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Name);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Number);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.AgentID);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Info);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Email);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.StartTime);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.EndTime);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Category);
  })
  .Pageable() 
  .Sortable()
```

)

Result on browser

```
{"Data":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Name1","Number":"040000000","AgentID":"1","Info":"info1","Email":"email1","StartTime":"\/Date(1360101600000)\/","EndTime":null,"Category":"Laser"},{"Id":3,"Name":"Name2","Number":"0400000000","AgentID":"2","Info":"info2","Email":"email2","StartTime":"\/Date(1360188000000)\/","EndTime":null,"Category":"Kaihi"}],"Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add jquery min js in your page add this jquery `Jquery-1.8.1.min.js` .

Comment: I think Kendo files and JQuery are loaded properly as i can get the data to grid by using .BindTo ViewBag Method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that your action method is return a JSON string while your view expect a list of `KendoUIMvcCim.Models.Customer`. Use two different action methods in your controller to address this:

1. First action returns a ViewResult and is needed for the View

   ```
   public ViewResult Index()
   {
     using (var db = new CimDataContext())
     {
       IQueryable<Customer> customers = db.Customers;
       return View(customers);
     }
   }
   ```
2. Second action returns ActionResult and is needed by your grid to populate it through the AJAX calls.

   ```
   public ActionResult Customers_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
   {
     using (var db = new CimDataContext())
     {
       IQueryable<Customer> customers = db.Customers;
       DataSourceResult result = customers.ToDataSourceResult(request);
       return Json(result, "text/x-json", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
   }
   ```

In your **Index.cshtml** file you finally need to change the `.Read` line so you're calling the right action method in your controller.

```
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource 
      .Ajax() 
      .Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customer")) 
   )
```

Comment: I've tried you example aswell, and same problem. Kendo files are loaded properly as i can get the data to grid by using .BindTo ViewBag Method. Thank you for commenting anyway!

Comment: @Porttila Please check my completely new answer. I remembered I had the same problem as you had and this is how I solved it!

Comment: Still struggling, now the Grid opens without any data. If i click on header to sort or something it just opens the same JSON input in text as before. Damn me, this shouldn't be this hard, been previously working mostly with VB.NET Windows apps so this is bit new for me.

Comment: In my upgraded example I'm sending data directly to the view and it's  needed for the grid to work properly. When I was preparing the first example for you I cut away too much of the code. I think it should be working now.

Comment: It was a damn mystery but working now, i'm not sure which went wrong because i am pretty sure i've tried it this way before. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you...I was struggling quite some myself when I started with Kendo Grids...

Comment: @Ohlin hi Ohlin , can you help on this Kendo grid issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61334924/kendo-grid-clienttemplate-if-else-condition

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old post but for anyone still struggling:

Be sure not to be including jquery 2 times if you are copying/pasting from the Kendo documentation, as you might already have it in your file.

That said, put the jQuery reference in the HEAD of your page, instead of the bottom, else the kendo grid will try to render with jQuery before it is actually imported.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Final working code:

Controller

```
public ViewResult Index()
    {      
            return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Customers_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        using (var db = new CimDataContext())
        {
            IQueryable<Customer> customers = db.Customers;
            DataSourceResult result = customers.ToDataSourceResult(request);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Index.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<KendoUIMvcCim.Models.Customer>()
  .Name("grid")
  .DataSource(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Read(read => read.Action("Customers_Read", "Customer")))
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Id);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Name);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Number);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.AgentID);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Info);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Email);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.StartTime);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.EndTime);
      columns.Bound(customer => customer.Category);
  })
  .Pageable() 
  .Sortable()
```

)