# Kendo UI Grid returns only pure JSON

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Similarly on [Kendo UI Grid returns JSON to browser (using MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829235/kendo-ui-grid-returns-json-to-browser-using-mvc) page Kendo UI Grid returns pure JSON instead of page. I have followed the steps mentioned on that page, but it did not solve the problem. Here is the Controller and View below:

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult _Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var myDatabase = new MyDataContext();
    var students = northwind.Students;

    // Avoid the circular reference by creating a View Model object and skiping the Customer property
    var result = students.ToDataSourceResult(request, o => new
    {
        ID = o.ID,
        Name = o.Name,
        Surname = o.Surname
    });

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Student>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Student>().Name("Grid")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.Bound(o => o.ID);
    columns.Bound(o => o.Name);
    columns.Bound(o => o.Surname);
})
.Pageable()
.Sortable() 
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax().Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ID)).Read("_Index", "Home")))
```

When I look at the Scripts and Css section on firebug, there are no script and no css. I am not sure what is the origin of this. How can I solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, you added js,css and dll for kendo ?

Comment: Yes, because it is a Kendo application and all te necessary javascript and css files are added automatically to the project. Furthermore, I created another layout and added the same files to this layout that my view use. But it did not make any sense. Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that I needed two ActionResult instead on one as in default MVC. So, for anyone who encounter this problem following usage solves the problem:

Are you sure that there are 2 definition (one for View,the other for retrieving data) in your controller and the View calls the other one as below?

**HomeController**

```
public ActionResult AjaxBinding()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult AjaxBinding_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var dataContext = new SampleEntities();

    IQueryable<OrderViewModel> result = dataContext.Orders.Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        OrderID = o.OrderID,
        ShipCity = o.ShipCity,
        ShipCountry = o.ShipCountry,
        ShipName = o.ShipName
    });
return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);      
}
```

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Order>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(o => o.OrderID).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCity);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipCountry);
        columns.Bound(o => o.ShipName);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("AjaxBinding_Read", "Home"))
    )
)
```